# Format Painter in Microsoft Office

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word

I know I can google it quite easily but hey, I have never asked any question @ SU, so here is one.

What is the shortcut key for Format Painter in Microsoft Office things e.g., Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to Copy Format and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Paste Format.

Comment: This only works in MS Word.

Comment: And in MS Outlook...

Comment: It does not work in Excel

Answer (score 3):

The official Office-wide Format Painter key combination is

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

---

This is awkward to press, though, especially when standing up.

So I automated this with an [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
^Numpad0::
Send, {ALTDOWN}hfp{ALTUP}
return
```

Comment: This is for copying the format. What is key combination for pasting it ?

Comment: Format painter isn't designed for pasting, it lets you highlight the piece of text that you want to apply the format too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no paste required - if Alt+h+f+p is done correctly, you should get the paintbrush appear, and you can then apply it, **but only to one location**.

HOWEVER: In the *mouse-click* version, double clicking on the Format Painter icon gives you the opportunity to apply the format multiple times, to numerous separate locations.

**How does one do that with the keyboard, for Excel?**

The answer from:

https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/word-run-format-painter-with-the-keyboard/

```
Click in the text with the formatting you want to apply.
Press Ctrl+Shift+C to copy the formatting (make sure you include the Shift    as Ctrl+C only copies the text).
Click in the text to which you want to apply the formatting.
Press Crtl+Shift+V. You can press this key combination as many times as you  like while the document is open — it retains the copied formatting until you do  step 2 again.
```

**...doesn't work for Excel.**

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the formatting (make sure you include the <kbd>Shift</kbd>    as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> only copies the text).
Click in the text to which you want to apply the formatting.
Press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Its works perfectly fine in MS Outlook as well.

Comment: To my eye this looks just like the accepted answer.  How does it differ?